# WooCommerce minimum order amount for specific country excluding local pickup

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to craft a code for WooCommerce to set a minimum order amount for specific countries, but I want to let them order if they select "local pickup" as their shipping method. Nevertheless, I can't make it work. I tried to look it up but couldn't find a post which explained it. I hope that you can give me some insights.

Thanks already in advance!

```
// Set a minimum amount of order based on shipping zone & shipping method before checking out

add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'cw_min_num_products' );

// Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
function cw_min_num_products() {
    
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
        global $woocommerce;

        // Set the minimum order amount, shipping zone & shipping method before checking out
        $minimum = 75;
        $county     = array('CH') || array('LI');
        $shipping_method    = 'local_pickup';
        
        // Defining var total amount      
        $cart_tot_order = WC()->cart->total;
        
        // Compare values and add an error in Cart's total amount
        // happens to be less than the minimum required before checking out.
        // Will display a message along the lines 
     
        if( $cart_tot_order < $minimum && in_array( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(), $county ) && WC()->shipping->get_shipping_methods() != $shipping_method ) {
            // Display error message
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>Sie haben die Mindestbestellmenge von $%s EUR noch nicht erreicht. Geringerer Bestellwert ist nur bei Selbstabholung möglich.</strong>' 
                . '<br />Ihre derzeitige Bestellmenge ist: $%s.',
                $minimum,
                $cart_tot_order ),
            'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$county = array('CH') || array('LI');` is wrong - that's not how you concatenate arrays. Why not just `$county = array('CH', 'LI');` ?

Answer (score 2):

Hey just wanted to let you know! I was able to achieve my desired result with this code!

```
// Set a minimum amount of order based on shipping zone & shipping method before checking out

add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'cw_min_num_products' );

// Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
function cw_min_num_products() {
    
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
        global $woocommerce;

        // Set the minimum order amount, shipping zone & shipping method before checking out
        $minimum = 75;
        $county     = array('CH','LI');
        $chosen_shipping = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0];
        $chosen_shipping = explode(':', $chosen_shipping);
        
        // Defining var total amount      
        $cart_tot_order = WC()->cart->subtotal;
        
        // Compare values and add an error in Cart's total amount
        // happens to be less than the minimum required before checking out.
        // Will display a message along the lines 
     
        if( $cart_tot_order < $minimum && in_array( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(), $county ) && $chosen_shipping[0] != 'local_pickup') {
            // Display error message
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>Sie haben die Mindestbestellmenge von €%s exklusive Versandkosten noch nicht erreicht. Geringerer Bestellwert ist nur bei Selbstabholung möglich.</strong>' 
                . '<br />Ihre derzeitige Bestellmenge ist: €%s.',
                $minimum,
                $cart_tot_order ),
            'error' );
        }
    }
}
```